# lattice with soft body versus mesh

Tags: physics, soft-body

Can someone explain why when I create a lattice and a cube as separate objects, i.e., the cube isn't controlled by the lattice, and make them both soft bodies and give them the same parameters in the Soft Body panel in the Physics properties, the lattice just crumples and collapses while the cube bounces around.

If I turn on Stiff Quads for the lattice then it behaves more like the cube. But not quite, the surface of the cube wiggles around a lot.  Both have been subdivided so that they are 6 squares across (the lattice with U, V, and W set to 7).

In the Object Data for the lattice I also turned on Outside but that doesn't help.  I would have thought that with that it would act like a soft body cube.

Comment: Here's the active vewport opengl render with Stiff Quads off: http://gfycat.com/AnxiousAdventurousAmericanbadger

Comment: Here's the render with Stiff Quads on: https://gfycat.com/AdventurousLimpGrison